# Save BufferedImages as TIFF

Tags: java, bufferedimage, tiff

I´m trying to save a BufferedImage as TIFF. This works fine, but it's taking too long per TIFF, up to 5 sec. 5 sec might not sound like much, but if you want to save up to 20 images it´s too long.

Here is my code:

```
public void convertToTif() throws ConvertionFailedException {
final int dpi = 300;

try {
    ImageOutputStream ios = null;
    TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();

    ImageWriter writer = tiffspi.createWriterInstance();

    // setup writer
    ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(this.tifFile);

    writer.setOutput(ios);

    BufferedImage tiffImage = create1BitTif(this.imageToConvert);

    // get new Metadata
    ImageTypeSpecifier imageType = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(tiffImage.getType());
    IIOMetadata imageMetadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, null);

    TIFFDirectory dir = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(imageMetadata);

    BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();
    TIFFTag tagXRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION);
    TIFFTag tagYRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION);
    TIFFTag tagNewSubfile = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_NEW_SUBFILE_TYPE);
    TIFFTag tagBitsPerSample = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
    TIFFTag tagResolutionUnit = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT);

    // set X DPI
    long[][] X_DPI = new long[][] { { dpi, 1 } };
    TIFFField xDPI = new TIFFField(tagXRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, X_DPI);
    // set Y DPI
    long[][] Y_DPI = new long[][] { { dpi, 1 } };
    TIFFField yDPI = new TIFFField(tagYRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, Y_DPI);

    // setzt Photometric von BlackIsZero auf WhiteIsZero
    TIFFField photometricInterpretationField = new TIFFField(base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION), BaselineTIFFTagSet.PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION_WHITE_IS_ZERO);

    // setzt NewSubfileType auf 0
    TIFFField newSubfile = new TIFFField(tagNewSubfile, 0);

    // setzt BitsPerSample auf 1
    TIFFField bitsPerSample = new TIFFField(tagBitsPerSample, 1);

    // setzt ResolutionUnit auf 2
    TIFFField resolutionUnit = new TIFFField(tagResolutionUnit, 2);

    dir.addTIFFField(xDPI);
    dir.addTIFFField(yDPI);
    dir.addTIFFField(photometricInterpretationField);
    dir.addTIFFField(newSubfile);
    dir.addTIFFField(bitsPerSample);
    dir.addTIFFField(resolutionUnit);

    TIFFImageWriteParam param = (TIFFImageWriteParam) writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setTIFFCompressor(new TIFFT6Compressor());
    param.setCompressionType("CCITT T.6");
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.0f);

    IIOMetadata streamMetadata = writer.getDefaultStreamMetadata(null);
    String tiffMetadataFormatName = streamMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName();
    IIOMetadataNode newTree = new IIOMetadataNode(tiffMetadataFormatName);

    // create little endian
    IIOMetadataNode endianNode = new IIOMetadataNode("ByteOrder");
    endianNode.setAttribute("value", "LITTLE_ENDIAN");

    newTree.appendChild(endianNode);
    streamMetadata.setFromTree(tiffMetadataFormatName, newTree);

    writer.prepareWriteSequence(streamMetadata);
    writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(tiffImage, null, dir.getAsMetadata()), param);

    ios.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ConvertionFailedException(e);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? If you are just looking for open-ended suggestions, that would be off topic here.

Comment: How big are the resulting TIFF files?

Comment: Have you profiled to see how your 5 seconds are spent (not saying that 5 seconds is a meaningful measure, unless you also say something about your CPU, disk speed, image size etc., but anyway...)? Also, why are you writing a single image as a sequence?

Comment: Sorry, my question is why it need so long? I don´t know exact how my 5 seconds are spent, but most of the 5 seconds need "writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(tiffImage, null, dir.getAsMetadata()), param);". The image size is about 150KB. It is a Multifunctionprinter with a Intel® Celeron® Processor U3405 1.07Ghz, DDR3-SDRAM 2GB. More information about the hardware i haven´t. haraldK i don´t now a other way to save.

Comment: I just measured the time and the comlete process need 7 seconds and by 7 seconds the "write" need 6 second.